# kube-state-metrics doesn't show hardware utilization

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I installed this yamls

https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/examples/standard

I can see CPU per pod utilization only from system pods such as: calico-node, coredns, controller...

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="kube-system",pod="coredns-66bff467f8-9tn5w",container="coredns",node="prd-web-k8s101.tech.test.com"} 0.1
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="kube-system",pod="calico-node-frlfk",container="calico-node",node="prd-web-dkr006.tech.test.com"} 0.25
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="kube-system",pod="calico-node-rp46l",container="calico-node",node="prd-web-dkr005.tech.test.com"} 0.25
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="kube-system",pod="coredns-66bff467f8-55dfn",container="coredns",node="prd-web-k8s101.tech.test.com"} 0.1
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{namespace="kube-system",pod="calico-node-sn72d",container="calico-node",node="prd-web-k8s101.tech.test.com"} 0.25
```

But there is no CPU/RAM metrics from my own deployment, only this type

kube_replicaset_created{namespace="alex",replicaset="deployment-nginx-5bf87f5f59"} 1.588430245e+09

My k8s version is 1.18 (kubeadm installation), bare metal, Centos 7.

Comment: Did you added roles for `kube-state-metrics` to view namespace `alex`?

Comment: of cause no, ClusterRole is a non-namespaced resource.

Comment: Can you post  an example `yaml` for your deployment?

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: No, I installed Prometheus inside k8s + scrape metrics with external Prometheus.